# Bootstrap3 x-editable and wysihtml5.js

Tags: twitter-bootstrap-3, x-editable, bootstrap-wysihtml5

I am trying to use Bootstrap 3 with x-editable latest version. X-editable is working fine with datetime, text, textarea field but it is not working with type "wysihtml5". There is no working example given for this in X-editable site however for bootstrap 2 working example given. So does X-editable supports this typefor bootstrap3 ?

Followed the below documents to include the css,js as mentioned and after jquery.
http://vitalets.github.io/x-editable/docs.html
https://github.com/jhollingworth/bootstrap-wysihtml5/tree/master/src

I have loaded all the library exactly mentioned in the documentation of x-editable and wysihtml5. Still I am getting a js error:

> wysihtml5.js uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'inherit' of
>   undefined
>
> Problem is in
>   line(bootstrap3-editable-1.5.1/inputs-ext/wysihtml5/wysihtml5.js) : 
>   $.fn.editableutils.inherit(Wysihtml5,
>   $.fn.editabletypes.abstractinput);

`$.fn.editableutils` is coming as `"undefined"` where as `$.fn` does have different object and not editabeutils.

Can someone please guide as what can be the issue and how to resolve it ? I want to use x-edtable with type wysihtml5 for Bootstrap 3.

Comment: Please share the relevant parts of your code

Comment: Issue is resolved and it is related with ordering of js file inclusion. I thought I have added it post jQuery and other library but it was my incorrect assumption. As soon as I moved the file inclusion script wysihtml, bootstrap-wysihtml5 and wysihtml5 to last, it started to work. Good to see the X-editable works with Bootstrap3. It is a great tool. Thanks Shiran for your time :)